# Is there a query to show all tables and views in SQLworkbench?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

It would really help me if you can give the query that i can run in Oracle's SQL Workbench to show list of all tables and views.

Comment: This might help you https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-list-all-tables/, https://www.databasestar.com/sql-list-tables/ or https://bridgitmendlermusic.com/how-do-i-view-data-in-a-mysql-workbench-table/#How_do_I_view_data_in_a_MySQL_workbench_table

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, I always thought Workbench was a MySQL thing and Oracle was Oracle(DB). I know that Oracle owns MySQL, and maybe workbench does connect to oracle these days (I've been in the SQLS camp for a long time) but you should clarify what database you're using when you ask questions as it's often a vital bit of info. Also when you say "show all tables and views" do you mean you want us to tell you have to click on so you see a nice UI tree of tables and views, or do you want us to provide you an SQL query you run that shows all tables and views in a results grid?